# Basic Github Repo Creation

Tags: github

I just created my first Github Repo through the Github Bash on Windows 10.

I ran:

```
$ mkdir Projects
$ mkdir Projects/DataScientistsToolbox
$ mkdir Projects/DataScientistsToolbox/sample
$ cd Projects/DataScientistsToolbox/sample
$ git init
Initialised empty Git repository in /home/osboxes/Projects/DataScientistsToolbox/sample/.git/
$ ls -la
```

I am really struggling with understanding this code. So I created three directories: projects, datascientiststoolbox, and sample.

1. What does the cd command on my code do?
2. Does the git init code run the creation?
3. What does the ls -la do?
4. Lastly, I can't seem to find where the repo is saved on my computer, is it located on the desktop or in a special spot?

Thank you, sorry about the large amount of questions.

Comment: Welcome to Git, and happy coding! These tutorials helped me understand how to use Git: http://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1 and http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

1. The `cd` command lets you **c**hange your working **d**irectory.
2. Yes, `git init` creates (initalizes) a new repository on your machine in your current working directory.
3. `ls` displays all files and directories in the current working directory. `-la` changes the way they are printed.
4. `pwd` makes your machine **p**rint the **w**orking **d**irectory. Use it to find out where your repository was created.

Read [here](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/) about how to create a *GitHub* Repository. And [this](http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/basic-unix.html) is a list of basic unix commands - it may help you to get started with unix systems.

Answer (score -1):

You created only **one** repository with `git init`. `cd` stands for `change directory`, it's like when you double-click a folder to open it.

So basically your repo is in `Projects/DataScientistsToolbox/sample`.

`ls` is used for listing all files in the current directory you're in. `-la` are flags for different styles of displaying (try running just `ls`).

Also, all these commands have nothing to do with GitHub. They're a part of git.

Comment: Is the my repo located on my computer now?

Comment: Your local repository is. I suggest you read more about git. [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is a great starting point.